# Diagnostic settings within Azure - Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I want to set up auditing on a SQL database so I see server and database auditing like below :

[image]

so this shows there is auditing on the SQL server and also the SQL db. I can do this quite easily in terraform by pointing to /master and I can get the server auditing done - so like this :

```
 #---- Diagnostic Logging ----
resource "azurerm_monitor_diagnostic_setting" "main" {
  name                       = "Diagnostic Settings - Master"
  target_resource_id         = "${azurerm_mssql_server.main.id}/databases/master"
  log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.main.id
  

  log {
    category = "SQLSecurityAuditEvents"
    enabled  = true

    retention_policy {
      enabled = false
    }
  }

  metric {
    category = "AllMetrics"

    retention_policy {
      enabled = false
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [log, metric]
  }
}
```

and this section applies it to the /master db (server).

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_server_extended_auditing_policy" "main" {
  server_id              = azurerm_mssql_server.main.id
  log_monitoring_enabled = true
}
```

although I need it on the server, I also need it on two databases which sit on the server. Any help with this because I cannot seem to sort it.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. As stated in the blue box on top of your screenshot, enabling Logging at server level will automatically enable Logging for all databases under that same server. You do not have to specify it in your tf file.

Comment: fair enough - the environmnet i treid to copy was wrong... although you can create an log analytic policy for db level if you require.

Comment: Absolutely, its all about your logging strategy. But as soon as you enable it at server level, then it prevails on db logging configuration - that is good to know :)

Answer (score 1):

Threre is no need to create a db level but if you do required it then. you can do this by changing this line to the name of your db.

```
 target_resource_id         = "${azurerm_mssql_server.main.id}/databases/master"
```

master points at you server level, but if you want a policy at the db level then change this to your db name.